# make rpm find dependencies in a specific location

Tags: centos, rpm, glibc

I was trying to install a software through rpm. However, it requires glibc-2.15. We only have glibc-2.12 on CentOS-6. I have installed a glibc-2.15 at a separate location.

So how can I make rpm to look for the libraries in the glic-2.15 location?
I found a rpmrebuild tool, but not sure what to add.

Comment: Perhaps the RPM is for CentOS 7?  Post your exact command line, if possible.  This question had a similar problem: http://superuser.com/questions/850276/how-to-resolve-rpm-dependencies

Comment: Don't try to mix and match RPMs from wrong distributions. It doesn't work and you only end up breaking stuff and making yourself (or your successors) work too hard for no good purpose.

Comment: Which application are your trying to install?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that happens when you mess about with glibc https://serverfault.com/questions/828737/centos-postgres-failed-to-start.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. `rpm` knows only about files that have been installed by an rpm (it keeps an internal database with installed files). So the best solution is to repackage yourself glibc-2.15 (using `rpmbuild --rebuild`)

Answer (score 0):

yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=

Try this command to download the required rpms